# MainActivity.kt doesn't see button's id?

Tags: android, kotlin

Code:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    button3.setOnClickListener { }
}
```

Screenshot of code with IDE error: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8SdN.png)

[image]

I haven't idea what the error might be. Reloading and rebuild didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing your code outside of `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` (or any other) method scope.

Your code is:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    button3.setOnClickListener { }
}
```

But must be:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button3.setOnClickListener { 
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

You can use class-level declaration for methods, inner classes etc, but not for writing code.

And calling views directly by their ids is possible only using [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html). Check if you're using it and move your code to the one of methods' scope, and code will works.

Answer (score 0):

All actions must be inside an any function. Your `button3.setOnClickListener { }` written outside the function. 
And when you add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` your app.gradle file, widgets can be used directly via ID. Without this you need to declare your btn.

Answer (score 0):

you must go in gradle scripts and select build.gradle(module.....)
and add this line:
(  id 'kotlin-android-extensions' )
in plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
here
}
and sync now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think that this point has already been addressed not only by the accepted answer but more specifically by @Fr099y. So I would recommend having a look at other answers before adding your own and also taking note of when this was originally posted, which was nearly 3 years ago.